# How to get Firefox history using C# application?

Tags: c#-4.0, firefox, windows-forms-designer

I need to retrieve the Firefox history(url) using C# windows Form application.

I am Using Firefox 17.0.1 version.

I have been tried with `DDEClient` class and `SQLLite` database. both are not working.

When I use the `DDEClient` class I can able to get the active tab URL from the Firefox, when I use the SQLLite Database, it is not working VS2010.

How can I achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
private static string dbName = "places.sqlite";
private static int dbColumnUrl = 1;
private static int dbColumnVisitDate = 9;

String strConnection = @"Data Source=" + newPath + @";Version=3;";

using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(strConnection))
{
    string query = "select * from moz_places;";
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                logger.Info("time: " + dr.GetValue(dbColumnVisitDate));
                logger.Info("URL: " + dr.GetValue(dbColumnUrl));
            }
        }
    }
}
```